# CSS animation with different effects on :hover and :active?

Tags: html, css

**EDIT** Demo is here : http://3.cnxical.appspot.com

The `text-shadow` property changes on hover, and with `animation-fill-mode` set `forwards` the state persists.

The animation for the :active state does not work, and nothing happens when the title is clicked.

The expected behaviour is the title should disappear because the `text-shadow` property was set to (and both of these were tried) `none` or `0 0 1px transparent`. Setting `text-shadow` for :active was also tried without an animation and it did not work.

How can the correct behaviour be achieved?

The code is :

```
            #title {
                position:absolute;
                cursor:pointer;
                text-align:center;
                top:15%;
                left:50%;
                -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
                color:transparent;
                text-shadow:0 0 10px lime;
                font-size:5vmin;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-family:"Courier New",Courier,monospace;
                -webkit-animation: push_title_focus 0.3s;
            }
            #title:active {
                -webkit-user-select:none;
                -webkit-animation: vanish_title 0.3s;   
            }
            #title:hover {
                -webkit-animation: pull_title_focus 0.3s;
                -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes pull_title_focus {
                from { text-shadow: 0 0 10px lime; }
                to { text-shadow: 0 0 1px lime; }
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes push_title_focus {
                from { text-shadow: 0 0 1px lime; }
                to { text-shadow: 0 0 10px lime; }
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes vanish_title {
                from { text-shadow: 0 0 1px lime; }
                to { text-shadow: none !important; }
            }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be #title:focus for when the title is clicked ?

Comment: I always thought focus is for tab focus, just a side effect of when clicked. Active is for clicked. What do you think?

Comment: I think I'm wrong - just tried it in a fiddle and it didn't work. However, you now have the right answer :o)

Comment: Yeah, it is for tab focus. If you tab through and the element is tabbable the :focus state will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press the mouse button down to activate the link, the mouse is still pointing to it, so it is still being hovered.

`#title:hover` and `#title:active` are equally specific, and the hover rule is defined last.

Any rules with properties that are specified in both rule-sets, will be overridden by the `:hover` rule (including `-webkit-animation`).

Reorder your rulesets so the `:hover` rule appears *before* the `:active` rule.

Comment: Awesome! It works, thank you. Accepting. However, isn't it more correct to say hover is just an event that fires, triggering the animation, so for the CSS, the element is not still being hovered. The state persists after hover triggers the animation only because fill-mode is forwards. What do you think?

Comment: Ok and for WebKit animations without fill mode forward the animation end state does not persist suggesting hover there is a single event on mouse over. What do you think?